# Assign a value to a variable on RETURN PL/SQPL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

Is there a way to achieve this in PL/SQL oracle ?

```
    RETURN (return_status:=1);
```

It gives a compilation error when I try to do this. If this is not possible please suggest a better alternative instead of doing

```
   return_status := 1;
   RETURN (return_status);
```

Comment: Are you looking for `RETURN 1;`?

Comment: Nopes I want to assign a value to return_status IN RETURN in one line rather than doing it two i.e. first assigning the value to return_status and then RETURN(return_status).

Comment: What's the problem with doing that in two lines?

Comment: Cause of the confusion: In some programming languages (like Java, where you came from), an assignment can also be used as an expression, so you can write `return a=1`, or `a = b = c = 1`.  PL/SQL is not such a language. Assignments are just statements and can't be used like that and you have to do it in two lines. There is no better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

When we execute a RETURN the procedure terminates at that point and control flow passes to the calling program. So there would be no value in this construct …

```
 RETURN (return_status:=1);
```

… because nothing in the program unit could act on `return_status` after the RETURN.

> this is a function and return_status is an OUT param

That's the root of your problem: poor design. Either return a value or have it as an OUT parameter but not both. The accepted practice in PL/SQL is that a function returns a value and has no OUT parameters. Only procedures (which don't have RETURN) have OUT parameters.

So you choices are:

1. `return 1` and don't have an OUT parameter
2. set OUT parameter = 1 and return something else
3. make it a procedure instead

Comment: Or 4, just do it in two lines, if you insist on keeping both the return value and the out parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what the problem is?

If you want to return the value return_status then the second option is just fine(if you are really doing a hardcoded assignment you could just return 1.

And I thought maybe you actually have an external variable return_status you are trying to change the value of by calling this function. In which case, use a procedure and have return_status be an IN OUT variable(maybe even just OUT).

Comment: @M.HarisAzfar If you're returning the value, you can't also be using that variable anywhere else afterwards - returning a value is the very last step in a function (unless an exception occurs). You can't have your cake and eat it in this case - you either set the variable somewhere, use it in the function and then return it, or you can just return the value directly, without needing to store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot assign value in the Oracle `FUNCTIONS RETURN` Statement.

From Oracle Docs, the syntax should be

> RETURN [[(] expression [)]];

For expression refer [**Expressions**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/expression.htm#GUID-D4700B45-F2C8-443E-AEE7-2BD20FFD45B8__CHDHFDEA)

Only solution i can think of  based on your requirement(1 condition instead of 2) is using `case expression`. Something like below  (if you have any condition)

```
RETURN
    CASE when return_status is not null  
         THEN 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions with OUT parameters are permitted but smell wrong.

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: There is no technical issue. It's more of a philosophical/hygiene thing. From the perspective of looking at the calling code, the "normal" behaviour of a function is to take some IN parameters and return a value. The fact that it returns a value is obvious from the invocation. The fact that the function is also modifying a parameter is only obvious if you look at the implementation/declaration of the function. If you need multiple values returned from a function, I would prefer to return a non-scalar datatype

Comment: or a procedure with multiple out params